# POST from a form to a custom action not being processed by the action - Routing error instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-action, rails-routing

I have a search form that needs to POST to 'users/search'. Following are the relevant code snippets:-

Form

```
<%=simple_form_for @user, :url => search_user_path(@user), :input_html => {:method => :post} do |f|%>
  <div id="top" style="width:979px; height:30px;">
    <%= select "search", :area_id, Area.find(:all).collect { |p| [p.name, p.id]}, {:selected => current_user.address.area}  %>
    <%= f.association :categories, :as => :check_boxes, :label => false%>
    <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I expect this to POST to users/:id/search

routes.rb

```
resources :users do    
  member do
    post 'search'
  end
end
```

rake routes | grep search

```
search_user POST   /users/:id/search(.:format)  {:action=>"search", :controller=>"users"}
```

So the route exists

Users controller has the following method

```
def search
  Rails.logger.debug('In users#search')
end
```

When I hit submit I get a Routing error

```
Started POST "/users/9/search" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-10-28 14:11:04 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/users/9/search"):
```

I am clueless on this and after a lot of wasted research I am resorting to the community for inputs. Any pointers will be hugely appreciated. Thanks.

FYI I am on rails 3.0.9 and ruby 1.9.2

-Tarun

Answer (score 1):

You need to write this in plural:

```
search_users_path(@user)
```

Also your form is a little bit weired. You could simply write

```
<%= form_for @user, search_users_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

Instead of

```
<%=simple_form_for @user, :url => search_user_path(@user), :input_html => {:method => :post} do |f|%>
```

You dont need the `:method => :post`

Comment: Can't use search_users_path since there is no such path. If you check my routes.rb you'll see that this is a member method and hence search_user_path(@user) is actually correct.

The form syntax is slightly different but I'm not sure if that matters here.